# Changing the onclick to a function with a variable as the argument

Tags: javascript, onclick

So here is a dumbed down version of what I'm doing.  I want to change the onclick for a span to call a function with a variable as its argument.  I want it to use the variable as it exists when I create the new onclick not as the variable is at the time of the click.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function share(it) {
  alert("We wanted 1, we got "+ it);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="key">Click me</span>

<script>
var x = 1;
document.getElementById('key').onclick = function() {share(x)}
x++;
</script>

</body>
</htmL>
```

Comment: You increment the variable only once, do it inside the function.

Comment: @elclanrs: *"...here is a dumbed down version of what I'm doing"* Pretty sure this is a very simple demo to illustrate the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a function() directly, use a function that creates the onclick function:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function share(it) {
  alert("We wanted 1, we got "+ it);
}

function makeFunction(x) {
return function() {share(x);}
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="key">Click me</span>

<script>
var x = 1;
document.getElementById('key').onclick = makeFunction(x)
x++;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function share(it) {
  alert("We wanted 1, we got "+ it);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="key">Click me</span>

<script>
function assign(y) {
   return function() { share(y); };
}
var x = 1;
document.getElementById('key').onclick = assign(x);
x++;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

make a copy of x and pass that to the function

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function share(it) {
  alert("We wanted 1, we got "+ it);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="key">Click me</span>

<script>
var x = 1;
var copyOfx = x + 0;
document.getElementById('key').onclick = function() {share(copyOfx)}
x++;
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is just declare the variable in the head. The variable is user-defined and hard coded, so it can load in the head and then just refer to it in the function when the click happens. You don't need to pass a parameter

Comment: When other code changes `x`, the handler will get the changed version., This is what OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: I might be misreading but couldn't a `var v` just be declared in the head and then a tiny snippet of script just be placed right below the variable of the document required in its initial state`<script>//set var v to something in the document that just finished loading</script>` and then only refer to the head variable when running the function

Comment: If you mean a separate variable, then yes, but any code that changes it accidentally or intentionally will be reflected in the handler.

Comment: well of course the handler wouldn't work directly with the copy which represents the desired initial state...that goes without saying because that's the whole thing we're trying to avoid. The handler would make a local copy of the data necessary.

Comment: Well then you're not showing how to make that copy. *That's* the question. And if a local copy is made, then there's no reason to make a separate variable.